# Using microphone with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, annyang

I am very new to raspberry pi. I want to use `annyang` speech recognition software (it is a speech recognition software for websites). But I am not understanding how to start working with microphone. (When I use `arecord` or `aplay` commands, it is showing error such as: `No such file in directory`).

Do I need to change any settings in the pi board to access microphone?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I added the annyang tag so people see which library you are using. Maybe you could post some code, so that it gets clearer what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry pi's do not have a built in microphone, you will need to use a USB microphone or connect a USB Sound Card and plug a microphone into that.

When you use arecord you will probably have to tell it to use the right device with a command similar to this:

```
arecord /home/pi/Desktop/a.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=1
```

Comment: Thanku hardillb. I am using Logitech Webcam Pro 9000( a USB webcam that comes with microphone). I will try this command and reply soon.

Comment: Could you please specify how to use the aplay command to play the audio files?

Comment: Ask a new question

Comment: Ok I will ask a new question.